# How to get the count of rows with values above a threshold + column index constrain?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following R dataframe:

```
      S.A1   S.A2   S.A3   S.B1   S.B2   S.B3
Loc1  0.3809 0.4444 0.5000 0.0011 0.0110 0.0003
Loc2  0.1762 0.2500 0.3333 0.5000 0.3250 0.2333
Loc3  0.2147 0.3500 0.2500 0.1428 0.2142 0.3000
Loc4  0.2382 0.4010 0.2222 0.3000 0.3095 0.3667
Loc5  0.0001 0.0120 0.0035 0.3333 0.4523 0.3333
Loc6  0.0095 0.0400 0.0490 0.1000 0.2321 0.1000
```

... and many more rows!

I would like to get the number of rows where I have values >= 0.05 **only on a few predefined columns**.

For instance:

- How many rows display values >= 0.05 on columns S.A1, S.A2 and S.A3 only?
  The answer is **unity**: this is Loc1.
- Oppositely, how many rows display values >= 0.05 on columns S.B1, S.B2 and S.B3 only? The answer is **two**: these are Loc5 and Loc6.

Column type S.A and S.B are mutually exclusive so Loc2, Loc3 and Loc4 will never be selected because these all display values >= 0.05 everywhere and not only on the predefined columns.

I have a reduced number of colums so it is possible to predefine columns indices (or names) manually for further selection, however, I cannot figure out how to process to select rows displaying values above a certain threshold while also adding a constrain on the colums in which such values could appear.

Any suggestion is welcome!

Cheers :)

Comment: Confused as to how Loc2, Loc3, and Loc4 do not display all values >= 0.05 when looking at S.A1, S.A2, and S.A3

Comment: Hi Adam, I really need to count only rows which display values >0.05 on a given column type, and S.A and S.B are mutually exclusive (I should have mentioned this with these terms, I will edit my original post if possible). In this situation, Loc 2, 3 and 4 would never be counted as these all display values > 0.05 everywhere and not only on S.A (or S.B) columns. Answers below provided great resources!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want, but I think you want this:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(S.A1 = runif(6), 
                S.A2 = runif(6), 
                S.A3 = runif(6), 
                S.B1 = runif(6), 
                S.B2 = runif(6),
                S.B3 = runif(6))
```

Because you did not provide a reproducible example I took the liberty of making df. Which looks like:

```
     S.A1      S.A2       S.A3       S.B1      S.B2       S.B3
1 0.7050447 0.3425170 0.24222797 0.89027284 0.6516980 0.12141078
2 0.5982959 0.9922373 0.87056458 0.43965606 0.6688127 0.05517046
3 0.9416712 0.5065097 0.01904794 0.08972336 0.6339239 0.63476302
4 0.8578870 0.7158088 0.28133235 0.02191547 0.6814373 0.50473500
5 0.5962874 0.8617246 0.04189701 0.59269613 0.6201409 0.32715440
6 0.1642811 0.2287726 0.76770094 0.22238414 0.9873463 0.06580177
```

We then select the columns in question and say all of these columns need to be greater than or equal to some cutoff value in this case 0.05 and get the number of rows.

```
df %>% select(S.A1,S.A2, S.A3) %>% filter(S.A1 >= .05 & S.A2 >= 0.05 & S.A3 >= 0.05) %>% nrow()
df %>% select(S.B1,S.B2, S.B3) %>% filter(S.B1 >= .05 & S.B2 >= 0.05 & S.B3 >= 0.05) %>% nrow()
```

This produces: `4` and `5`

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `dplyr::filter_at` on selected columns as:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% rownames_to_column() %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("S.A")), any_vars(. >= 0.50))
#   rowname   S.A1   S.A2 S.A3   S.B1  S.B2  S.B3
# 1    Loc1 0.3809 0.4444  0.5 0.0011 0.011 3e-04

df %>% rownames_to_column() %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("S.B")), any_vars(. >= 0.050))
#   rowname   S.A1  S.A2   S.A3   S.B1   S.B2   S.B3
# 1    Loc2 0.1762 0.250 0.3333 0.5000 0.3250 0.2333
# 2    Loc3 0.2147 0.350 0.2500 0.1428 0.2142 0.3000
# 3    Loc4 0.2382 0.401 0.2222 0.3000 0.3095 0.3667
# 4    Loc5 0.0001 0.012 0.0035 0.3333 0.4523 0.3333
# 5    Loc6 0.0095 0.040 0.0490 0.1000 0.2321 0.1000
```

***Note:*** If OP's intention is to check for condition on all selected columns then once can replace `any_vars` with `all_vars` in above code.

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"S.A1   S.A2   S.A3   S.B1   S.B2   S.B3
Loc1  0.3809 0.4444 0.5000 0.0011 0.0110 0.0003
Loc2  0.1762 0.2500 0.3333 0.5000 0.3250 0.2333
Loc3  0.2147 0.3500 0.2500 0.1428 0.2142 0.3000
Loc4  0.2382 0.4010 0.2222 0.3000 0.3095 0.3667
Loc5  0.0001 0.0120 0.0035 0.3333 0.4523 0.3333
Loc6  0.0095 0.0400 0.0490 0.1000 0.2321 0.1000",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, Adam and MKR.

I should have mentioned that I do not want to select columns where both S.A and S.B columns display > 0.05 values, since S.A and S.B are mutually exclusive (at least I want to select rows where this is the case). However, this is easy to implement with the functions you suggested.

For instance using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% select(S.A1,S.A2, S.A3, S.B1, S.B2, S.B3) %>% filter(S.A1 >= 0.05 & S.A2 >= 0.05 & S.A3 >= 0.05 & S.B1 < 0.05 & S.B2 < 0.05 & S.B3 < 0.05) %>% nrow()
df %>% select(S.A1,S.A2, S.A3, S.B1, S.B2, S.B3) %>% filter(S.B1 >= 0.05 & S.B2 >= 0.05 & S.B3 >= 0.05 & S.A1 < 0.05 & S.A2 < 0.05 & S.A3 < 0.05) %>% nrow()
```

I just need to add extra condition where S.A should be all >= 0.05 but S.B < 0.05, and then the reverse situation. I am not sure how to do the same with `tidyverse` but the suggestion provided by MKR will sure be useful for further interrogations or other people!

Thank you very much!